# Change select to check boxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, select, checkbox, attributes

The reason I would like to do this, is that it will be situational. If a user is logged in, they will see drop downs. If not, they will see a list of text. Ideally just plain text, but I don't know if that's possible, so I was thinking I could convert the `<select>` to checkboxes and hide the check boxes with CSS.

Basically we don't want a user who isn't logged in to feel they can select anything, because they won't be able to order and this could lead to frustration. But we would still like them to view what options are available for each product as unselectable text. If there is a better way to do this than what I'm thinking, I'd be grateful for suggestions. For now, this is what I've patched together, but it's not changing the select to checkboxes.

I grabbed some code from here to use as a starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Also, I can't grab the < select > by id, because this will be on all < select >'s.

```
<select id="unique_id" class="unique_class"  data-attribute_name="unique_attribute_name" name="unique_name">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
    <option class="attached enabled" value="516">5/16"</option>
    <option class="attached enabled" value="38">3/8"</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")[0].setAttribute("type", "checkbox"); 
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d4qdekom/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should convert your select to checkboxes, provided there is an HTML element with an id of "container" to append the new checkboxes.

This is the HTML

```
<select id="unique_id" class="unique_class" data-attribute_name="unique_attribute_name" name="unique_name">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
    <option class="attached enabled" value="516">5/16"</option>
    <option class="attached enabled" value="38">3/8"</option>
</select>

<div id="container"></div>
```

The JavaScript function to transform the select to checkboxes below

```
function myFunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById('unique_id');
    var container = document.getElementById('container'); 
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
        var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
        checkbox.name = 'option';
        checkbox.id = 'randomId' + i;
        checkbox.value = select.options[i].text;
        var label = document.createElement('label')
        label.htmlFor = 'randomId' + i;
        label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(select.options[i].text));
        container.appendChild(checkbox);
        container.appendChild(label);
    }
}
```

You can then go ahead and remove the select from the DOM. I guess all these should be made easier with JQuery

This is an update using getElementsByTagName:

```
var selects = x.getElementsByTagName('SELECT');  // this is a node list
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
  var select = selects[i]; // this is a single select element
  // You can call the above function on each select here...
}
```

[This is a working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hbs8ms9w)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mustapha, thank you this is reeeaaaallly close! Only problem is, as I do mention in my question, I can't grab it by ID. Because I will need to do this on every select, there are 17, so I'd have to write `getElementById` 17 times. Which I guess I could do if it's the only way. What do you think?

Comment: If I get you right and you can't grab by ID, using `getElementsByTagName` should give you the `SELECT` you want and you can iterate through them and call the function to convert each value of the select on each iteration to whatever you want to convert to, even if not checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) I am having an issue though. I am swapping out `var select = document.getElementById('unique_id');` for `var select = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");` and this isn't working. I'm looking at the working jsFiddle and I can't tell why this swap wouldn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah `document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")` returns an array-like node list. So you need to iterate through the node list first. That means you will be having two iterations. The first being looping through the node list and the second to loop through each `SELECT` (element) in the nodelist)

Comment: Updated the answer and jsFiddle to reflect the change using `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your goal correctly, you can just put div's in and hide/show or enable/disable the div's depending on if the user is logged in or not. So wrap your select up in a div and just toggle that.

This would avoid trying to change the html by simply showing/hiding or enabling/disabling what you want the user to see.

Comment: Hi Devon, thanks for answering. I'm not sure that would be a solution though. I can hide the drop down menus when a user is not logged in, but I'd still like to display the values so they can view them without selecting them. If I do what you're suggesting (correct me if I'm wrong) I would still need to find a way to extract the values from the select menu, which puts me back at square 1.

Comment: So when you do the second div (for when the user is not logged in) don't have it submit anywhere. It can just be a form with all the same data but just does not submit.

Comment: Or you could always use some form of JavaScript or PHP validation to check if they are logged in before submitting the form (completing the order, etc). Depending on where the form submits you can ask the user to log in there to complete their order or whatever you are doing.

Comment: I am currently hiding the selects and add to cart button with `<?php if (!is_user_logged_in()): ?>` but my goal is to take the options out of the drop down and display them as plain text for users who are not logged in. I don't want them to see it in a selectable context because that will be bad UX. So if I use a second div that I can show/hide, that second div will somehow need to know what options exist in the select. So I'm wondering how I would do that.

Comment: You can use jQuery to get all the items in your select.

    $("#selectID option").each(function()
{
   console.log($(this).val());
  });